# Cannot trigger mat-checkbox change event using template reference variable

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `table` with two `columns` - `mat-checkbox` in one and the other holds a `String`. The idea is that when the string cell is clicked it will trigger `mat-checkbox.change` event.

I have referenced a `mat-checkbox` within an a for-loop using template reference variable. I am able access and set its `checked` value, however, I am not able to access the `(change)` event anymore (it worked previously).

I recently implemented changes that render `availableRoles` to be `null` and since then (and the respective `*ngIf` implementation) I am unable to trigger change action from `(click)="roleCheck.change"` event.

**Issue referenced is in `<tbody>` block**

```
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th class="border-right-0">
                    <mat-checkbox (change)="groupRoleCheckToggle()" [checked]="groupRoleCheckState == 2"
                        [indeterminate]="groupRoleCheckState == 1">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                </th>
                <th class="text-center border-left-0 w-100">
                    Roles
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <ng-container  *ngIf="availableRoles">
                <tr *ngFor="let role of availableRoles">
                    <td class="border-right-0">
                        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="selectRole(role)"
                            [checked]="role.selected" #roleCheck>
                        </mat-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border-left-0" (click)="roleCheck.change">
                        <span class="ml-3">
                            {{role.name}}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
            <tr *ngIf="!availableRoles">
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                    <i>
                        Please select a group...
                    </i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential solution in this particular case is also to call `selectRole(role)` method from click event on the `String` column. Effectively the below code would achieve the required functionality provided that the `selectRole` method controls the `selected` state.

```
                <td class="border-left-0" (click)="selectRole(role)">
                    <span class="ml-3">
                        {{role.name}}
                    </span>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try change
`(change)="selectRole(role)"`
to
`(change)="selectRole($event,role)"`

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck

Answer (score 0):

In your case please try out this,

```
<td class="border-left-0" 
    (click)="roleCheck._onInputClick($event)">
         <span class="ml-3">
           {{role.name}}
         </span>
  </td>
```

Actually `_onInputClick($event)` is the event we need to call on checkbox template reference. It will trigger the `(change)` event.